# можно ли такую запись сократить или оптимизировать

Tags: javascript

```
let bool = true
setInterval(() => {
    if(bool){
        document.body.style.background = 'red'
        bool = !bool
    }else{
        document.body.style.background = 'blue'
        bool = !bool
    }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: document.body.style.background = bool ? 'red' : 'blue'; bool = !bool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и без вспомогательной переменной:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  document.body.style.background =
    document.body.style.background === 'blue' ?  'red' : 'blue';
}, 1000);
```